# Rcpp equivalent for rowsum

Tags: c++, r, eigen, rcpp, armadillo

I am looking for a fast alternative for the R function `rowsum` in C++ / Rcpp / Eigen or Armadillo.

The purpose is to get the sum of elements in a vector `a` according to a grouping vector `b`. For example:

```
> a
 [1] 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2    
> b
 [1] 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 2
> rowsum(a,b)
  [,1]
1   10
2   10
```

Writing a simple for loop in `Rcpp` is very slow, but maybe my code was just inefficient.

I tried also to call the function `rowsum` in `Rcpp`, however, `rowsum` is not very fast.

Comment: The code does not use the offered data. You are using `rowsum` on a vector when it is designed to be used with matrices. You have offered no Cpp code.

Comment: `rowsum` dispatches `rowsum.default` in the above case and that already calls out to C code so it should be reasonably fast already.  You might be able to get a tiny bit of speed improvement by directly calling `rowsum.default` or `.Internal(rowsum_matrix(...))` although the latter is discouraged and is not allowed on CRAN.

Comment: Have you checked the Armadillo manual here: http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#sum There are at least some sum functions, do the suit your purpose?

Comment: Sounds like something `data.table` would excel at...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my attempt at doing this using `Rcpp` (first time using the package, so do point out my inefficiencies):

```
library(inline)
library(Rcpp)

rowsum_helper = cxxfunction(signature(x = "numeric", y = "integer"), '
  NumericVector var(x);
  IntegerVector factor(y);

  std::vector<double> sum(*std::max_element(factor.begin(), factor.end()) + 1,
                          std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN());
  for (int i = 0, size = var.size(); i < size; ++i) {
    if (sum[factor[i]] != sum[factor[i]]) sum[factor[i]] = var[i];
    else sum[factor[i]] += var[i];
  }

  return NumericVector(sum.begin(), sum.end());
', plugin = "Rcpp")

rowsum_fast = function(x, y) {
  res = rowsum_helper(x, y)
  elements = which(!is.nan(res))
  list(elements - 1, res[elements])
}
```

It's pretty fast for Martin's example data, but will only work if the factor consists of non-negative integers and will consume memory on the order of the largest integer in the factor vector (one obvious improvement to the above is to subtract min from max to decrease memory usage - which can be done in either the R function or the C++ one).

```
n = 1e7; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, T)

system.time(rowsum(x,f))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   14.241  0.170  14.412

system.time({tabulate(f); sum(x)})
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.216   0.027   0.252

system.time(rowsum_fast(x,f))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.313   0.045   0.358
```

Also note that a lot of the slowdown (as compared to `tabulate`) happens in the R code, so if you move that to C++ instead, you should see more improvement:

```
system.time(rowsum_helper(x,f))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.210   0.018   0.228
```

---

Here's a generalization that will handle almost any `y`, but will be a little bit slower (I'd actually prefer doing this in Rcpp, but don't know how to handle arbitrary R types there):

```
rowsum_fast = function(x, y) {
  if (is.numeric(y)) {
    y.min = min(y)
    y = y - y.min
    res = rowsum_helper(x, y)
  } else {
    y = as.factor(y)
    res = rowsum_helper(x, as.numeric(y))
  }

  elements = which(!is.nan(res))

  if (is.factor(y)) {
    list(levels(y)[elements-1], res[elements])
  } else {
    list(elements - 1 + y.min, res[elements])
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Not an answer, but maybe helpful for framing the issue. Seems like worst-case performance is to sum many short groups, and this seems to scale linearly with the size of the vector

```
> n = 100000; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, TRUE)
> system.time(rowsum(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.228   0.000   0.229 
> n = 1000000; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, TRUE)
> system.time(rowsum(x, f)) 
   user  system elapsed 
  1.468   0.040   1.514 
> n = 10000000; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, TRUE)
> system.time(rowsum(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
 17.369   0.748  18.166
```

There seem to be two short-cuts available, avoiding re-ordering

```
> n = 10000000; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, TRUE)
> system.time(rowsum(x, f, reorder=FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
 16.501   0.476  17.025
```

and avoiding an internal coercion to character

```
> n = 10000000; x = runif(n); f = as.character(sample(n/2, n, TRUE)); 
> system.time(rowsum(x, f, reorder=FALSE))
   user  system elapsed 
  8.652   0.268   8.949
```

And then the basic operations that would seem to be involved -- figuring out the unique values of the grouping factor (to pre-allocate a result vector) and doing the sum

```
> n = 10000000; x = runif(n); f = sample(n/2, n, TRUE)
> system.time({ t = tabulate(f); sum(x) })
   user  system elapsed 
  0.640   0.000   0.643
```

so yes, it seems like there's quite a bit of scope for a faster single-purpose implementation. This seems like a natural for `data.table`, and not too hard to implement in C. Here's a mixed solution, using R to do the tabulation and the 'classic' C interface to do the sum

```
library(inline)

rowsum1.1 <- function(x, f) {
    t <- tabulate(f)
    crowsum1(x, f, t)
}

crowsum1 = cfunction(c(x_in="numeric", f_in="integer", t_in = "integer"), "
    SEXP res_out;
    double *x = REAL(x_in), *res;
    int len = Rf_length(x_in), *f = INTEGER(f_in);

    res_out = PROTECT(Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, Rf_length(t_in)));
    res = REAL(res_out);
    memset(res, 0, Rf_length(t_in) * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        res[f[i] - 1] += x[i];
    UNPROTECT(1);
    return res_out;
")
```

with

```
> system.time(r1.1 <- rowsum1.1(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.276   0.092   1.373
```

To actually return a result that is identical to `rowsum`, this needs to be shaped as a matrix with appropriate dim names

```
rowsum1 <- function(x, f) {
    t <- tabulate(f)
    r <- crowsum1(x, f, t)
    keep <- which(t != 0)
    matrix(r[keep], ncol=1, dimnames=list(keep, NULL))
}

> system.time(r1 <- rowsum1(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  9.312   0.300   9.641
```

so for all that work we're only 2x faster (and much less general -- x must be numeric, f must be integer; no NA values). Yes, there are inefficiencies, e.g., allocating space levels that have no counts (though this avoids an expensive coercion to character vector for names).

Comment: Wow, I am impressed! That is pretty much exactly what I was looking for! My framework requires the specifications of rowsum1, x is numeric and f are integers. And anyhow, your function is 4x faster than rowsum on my Computer. :)

Comment: Martin. IIRC, `Rf_allocVector` does not set the initial values to 0.0. I think initial values of `res[i]` are garbage

Comment: @RomainFrancois oops, fixed, thanks.

Comment: Also, thinking about this some more. The `which` test in `rowsum1` could be wrong about which to keep (same problem on my answer I guess), e.g. with x = `c(1,-1,1,-1)` and f = `c(1L,1L,2L,2L)`.

Comment: `which(t != 0)` is better, thanks again Romain. Even more discouraging -- a lot of work, incomplete implementation, new bugs, and still not that much faster.

Comment: Still. This is an interesting test case for `Rcpp`. I will turn this into an issue in the `Rcpp` gallery. Could be worth generalizing (other functions, several factors, etc ...)

Answer (score 5):

To complement Martin's code, here is some `Rcpp` based version.

```
int increment_maybe(int value, double vec_i){
    return vec_i == 0 ? value : ( value +1 ) ;  
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector cpprowsum2(NumericVector x, IntegerVector f){
    std::vector<double> vec(10) ;
    vec.reserve(1000); 
    int n=x.size(); 
    for( int i=0; i<n; i++){
        int index=f[i]; 
        while( index >= vec.size() ){
            vec.resize( vec.size() * 2 ) ;    
        }
        vec[ index ] += x[i] ;
    }
    // count the number of non zeros
    int s = std::accumulate( vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, increment_maybe) ; 
    NumericVector result(s) ;
    CharacterVector names(s) ;

    std::vector<double>::iterator it = vec.begin() ;
    for( int i=0, j=0 ; j<s; j++ ,++it, ++i ){
        // move until the next non zero value
        while( ! *it ){ i++ ; ++it ;}
        result[j] = *it ;
        names[j]  = i ;
    }
    result.attr( "dim" ) = IntegerVector::create(s, 1) ;
    result.attr( "dimnames" ) = List::create(names, R_NilValue) ; 
    return result ;
}
```

The C++ code deals with everything, including formatting into the matrix format given by [`rowsum`](http://help.r-enthusiasts.com/library/base/html/rowsum.html), and shows (slightly) better performance (at least on the example).

```
# from Martin's answer
> system.time(r1 <- rowsum1(x, f))
   user  system elapsed
  0.014   0.001   0.015

> system.time(r3 <- cpprowsum2(x, f))
   user  system elapsed
  0.011   0.001   0.013

> identical(r1, r3)
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice work. Feel like writing it up for the Rcpp Gallery? ;-)

Comment: Maybe. I gotta get familiar with the whole process anyway.

Comment: Nothing to it -- don't let the git stuff confuse you.  Look at any one post, see the 'source' link and look at its source. Either .cpp with comments, or .Rmd.  We can continue over Google Chat / Hangouts if you want.

Comment: @Dirk, you should do that! :)

Answer (score 1):

In a comment and 'answer' that @Ben has deleted, it turns out that `f` is ordered and increasing.

```
n = 1e7; x = runif(n);
f <- cumsum(c(1L, sample(c(TRUE, FALSE), n - 1, TRUE)))
```

So

```
rowsum3 <- function(x, f)
{
    y <- cumsum(x)
    end <- c(f[-length(f)] != f[-1], TRUE)
    diff(c(0, y[end]))
}
```

is a common R solution (if one is not too concerned about precision), and

```
crowsum3 <- cfunction(c(x_in="numeric", f_in="integer"), "
    int j = 0, *f = INTEGER(f_in), len = Rf_length(f_in), 
        len_out = len == 0 ? 0 : f[len - 1];
    SEXP res = Rf_allocVector(REALSXP, len_out);
    double *x = REAL(x_in), *r = REAL(res);
    memset(r, 0, len_out * sizeof(double));
    for (int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        if (i != 0 && f[i] != f[i-1]) ++j;
        r[j] += x[i];
    }
    return res;
")
```

could be a C solution. These have timings

```
> system.time(r3 <- rowsum3(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.116   0.120   1.238 
> system.time(c3 <- crowsum3(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.080   0.000   0.081
```

and the loss of precision in the R implementation is apparent

```
> all.equal(r3, c3)
[1] TRUE
> identical(r3, c3)
[1] FALSE
```

`rowsum_helper` has

```
> system.time(r2 <- rowsum_helper(x, f))
   user  system elapsed 
  0.464   0.004   0.470
```

but also assumes 0-based indexing so

```
> head(rowsum_helper(x, f))
[1]       NaN 0.9166577 0.4380485 0.7777094 2.0866507 0.7300764
> head(crowsum3(x, f))
[1] 0.9166577 0.4380485 0.7777094 2.0866507 0.7300764 0.7195091
```

Comment: Same here, beware on non initialized values for `res`.

Comment: @RomainFrancois no, the original version initialized `r` correctly; `crowsum3(numeric(), integer())` didn't do good things, though!