# Sum in groups with RcppParallel

Tags: r, rcpp

I have written a function that desirably sums values in groups. It takes two vectors of the same length: `v` and `g` and should return a vector of length the same as unique elements in `g`. Groups are encoded as integers starting from zero. Using `Rcpp::sourceCpp` the code compiles but when called from R (`sg(runif(6), rep(0:1,each = 3))` for example) returns `numeric(0)`.

```
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct SumsInGroups: public Worker
{
  const RVector<double> v;
  const RVector<int> g;

  RVector<double> s;

  SumsInGroups(const NumericVector v, const IntegerVector g, NumericVector s): v(v), g(g), s(s) {}
  SumsInGroups(const SumsInGroups& p, Split): v(p.v), g(p.g), s(p.s) {}

  void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
    for (std::size_t i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
      if (s[g[i]] != s[g[i]]) s[g[i]] = v[i];
      else s[g[i]] += v[i];
    }
  }

  void join(const SumsInGroups& rhs) {
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
      s[i] += rhs.s[i];
    }
  }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RVector<double> sg(NumericVector v, IntegerVector g) {
  NumericVector s;
  SumsInGroups p(v, g, s);
  parallelReduce(0, v.length(), p);
  return p.s;
}
```

I am very new to `RcppParallel` so any comments and suggestions are welcomed.

Comment: Oh and forgotten to add a [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16975034/rcpp-equivalent-for-rowsum) to `Rcpp` code summing values in groups.

Comment: The code in the link initializes vector with NaN. You do not do this. Maybe this is a problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `s`. I suggest initializing with zeroes. Here is the code which worked for me. Note that since I initialize with zeroes, I do not need the checking you do in operator `()`.

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppParallel)]]
#include <RcppParallel.h>
using namespace Rcpp;
using namespace RcppParallel;

struct SumsInGroups: public Worker
{
    const RVector<double> v;
    const RVector<int> g;

    RVector<double> s;

    SumsInGroups(const NumericVector v, const IntegerVector g, NumericVector s): v(v), g(g), s(s) {}
    SumsInGroups(const SumsInGroups& p, Split): v(p.v), g(p.g), s(p.s) {}

    void operator()(std::size_t begin, std::size_t end) {
        for (std::size_t i = begin; i < end; ++i) {
            s[g[i]] += v[i];
        }
    }

    void join(const SumsInGroups& rhs) {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            s[i] += rhs.s[i];
        }
    }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
RVector<double> sg(NumericVector v, IntegerVector g) {
    NumericVector s(*std::max_element(g.begin(), g.end()) + 1);
    SumsInGroups p(v, g, s);
    parallelReduce(0, v.length(), p);
    return p.s;
}

/*** R
set.seed(101)
o <- runif(15)
i <-sample(0:3,15, rep = TRUE)
sg(o, i)
tapply(o, i, sum)
*/
```